# Android Java decryption - saving the decrypted file

Tags: java, android, encryption, save, aes

So I'm working on an application where I need to decrypt encrypted files.The encryption is done with PHP and decryption with Java.I've tested,there is no problem with the encryption/decryption in Java program.But my problem is that I can't run the same application in Android.I need to find away how to get the encrypted data.For now i prefer to store it in assets folder manually, just for tests and get it like this :

```
AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("AUDIOVISUALFOTO02.pdf"); //or image file
```

After that I need to save the decrypted file somewhere so I can see if decryption is working on the device too.So basically I need to find a way how to get the encrypted file from assets folder as example and where to store the decrypted file (dowsn't matter where).Here is the code that I'm using for decryption :

```
package com.android.decrypt;

import java.io.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

    public class DecryptPDFActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890abcde".getBytes(), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba9876543210".getBytes());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        //FileInputStream fis   = new FileInputStream(new File("encrypted.pdf"));
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(new File("decrypted.pdf"));

        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        int i;

        while ((i = cis.read(b)) != -1) {
          fos.write(b, 0, i);
        }
        fos.flush(); fos.close();
        cis.close(); fis.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error", "Damned ! : "+e);
        }
      }
}
```

So any help or suggestions how to do this are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you are asking.

If you are trying to read a file from the assets folder there are several examples on SO.

[Android Assets No Value Read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034615/android-assets-no-value-read)

Why not just use the file system rather than the assets folder in the apk?

Comment: It was just for a test,not for a real app.That's why I am using assets folder.Thanks for the answer anyway!